# Being inside multiple window managers at the same time

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, kde, window-manager

I'm in Gnome but if I logout I can get to a menu where I can choose KDE as well as other window managers. The problem is I have a program that's running inside Gnome and I don't want to stop it. Is there some way I can get into KDE without having to stop this program?

Comment: There's also Xephyr and Xnest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't there a `switch user` option on the logout screen which keeps the original user logged in but allows the second one to log in as well?

Alternatively you could log into a terminal, say VT1, and issue the command:

```
startx -- :1
```

which will start a second graphical console on VT8.

Answer (score 1):

Does this program have a window? or can it just run in the background?

If it's just running on a terminal, one simple thing you can use screen to keep the process running.

Also look at the the [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command

Comment: It has a window. It's VMWare Player. If it was VMWare server, then it could run in the backgroiund, but it's not. Will bg make it run in the backgroun?

Comment: `bg` won't help here.

Answer (score 1):

I once used the gdm.conf to do so. 
And as following link mentioned, this not gonna work as before.

> Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)
>
> The steps are the same as 9.10 -- GDM
>   2.30 and ConsoleKit 0.4.1 do not have native Multiseat support, nor will GDM
>   lauch two static X sessions like it
>   used to in 2.20. If you do not want to
>   use KDM, Multiseat branches exist for
>   GDM and ConsoleKit; they are described
>   here:

You can check more details on page to use kdm to get this done:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX